# Matlab: reshape 3-dimensional array into 2-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, matlab, reshape

I have a 3x3x2000 array of rotation matrices that I need to transform into a 2000x9 array.

I think I have to use a combination of permute() and reshape(), but I don't get the correct output order.

This is what I need:

```
First row of 3x3 array needs to be columns 1:3 in the output
Second row of 3x3 array needs to be columns 4:6 in the output
Third row of 3x3 array needs to be columns 7:9 in the output
```

I have tried all possible combinations of numbers 1 2 3 in the following code:

```
out1 = permute(input, [2 3 1]);
out2 = reshape(out1, [2000 9]);
```

But I always end up with the wrong order. Any tips for a Matlab newbie?

Comment: Give a small example of input **and** desired output, it will help potential volunteers to know if they get it right. Tip: You may have to include some transpose (`.'`) operations in your transformations, and do not forget that _Matlab_ is `column major` (e.g. _linear indexing works by column rather than lines_).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a simple `for`-loop?

```
for i=1:size(myinput,3)
    myoutput(i,:)=[myinput(1,:,i) myinput(2,:,i) myinput(3,:,i)];
    % or
    % myoutput(i,:)=reshape(myinput(:,:,i),[],9);
end
```

It's not simple as using `permute` and `reshape`, but it is transparent and easier for debugging. Once everything in your program runs perfectly, you can consider to rewrite such `for`-loops in your code...

Answer (score 1):

You had a mix-up in your `permute`

```
a = reshape(1:9*6, 3, 3, []);
```

`a` is a 3x3x6 matrix, each

```
a(:,:,i) = 9*(i-1) + [1 4 7
                      2 5 8
                      3 6 9];
```

So

```
out1 = permute(a, [3,1,2]);
out2 = reshape(out1, [], 9);
```

Or in one line

```
out3 = reshape(permute(a, [3,1,2]), [], 9);
```

So

```
out2 = out3 =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18
    19    20    21    22    23    24    25    26    27
    28    29    30    31    32    33    34    35    36
    37    38    39    40    41    42    43    44    45
    46    47    48    49    50    51    52    53    54
```